# Load balancing across RPCs

Tags: rpc

I’m looking for resources on how to implement a front end load balancing mechanism for splitting traffic across RPCs.

I know polkadot.js.org has something running that does this and I think it might be in this code (https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/apps-config/src/endpoints/util.ts)

Is this the right piece of code to get ideas from?

If anyone wants to collaborate on this let me know. Basically every project in the ecosystem needs this piece of code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.